# How can I return array elements specified in one line using an array of indexes?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, dictionary

Is there a way for me to say I want some specific values from an array, possibly used in a way such as this?

```
string[] values = new string[]{"boogie","woogie","all","night"};

string[] refinedValues = values.GetIndexes(new int[]{ 0, 2 });
```

In this situation, `refinedValues` would be an array containing the values `"boogie"` and `"all"`.

Comment: not built in - but you could write it yourself.

Comment: So is your question about how to write `GetIndexes`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
var refinedValues = new[] { 0, 2 }.Select(values.ElementAt);
```

A custom extension method would look like this

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetValues<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, params Int32[] indices) {
        return indices.Select(enumerable.ElementAt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity I did some benchmarking. This solution is by far the fastest one with large numbers of `values`, compared to Jonesy's solution or to a thing I tried myself with `join`. I think this is because `indices.Select` only does the number of iterations in `indices` and per iteration efficiently finds the array index.

Comment: Yeah, I have implemented it with a CSV parser that can request specific columns by field name. I have a test CSV file with 1.6 million records and 9 fields. Not surprisingly, the number of fields recorded does not affect the run time of the operation. Overall, it takes 15 seconds to process the data into an appropriate list. It's not bad, but I might have to parse the file by character rather than extending the .Net solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use a bit of LINQ:

```
string[] values = new string[] { "boogie", "woogie", "all", "night" };

var indexes = new[] {0, 2};
string[] refinedValues = values.Where((e, i) => indexes.Contains(i)).ToArray();

//refined-values contains "boogie", "all"
```